# PostgreSQL reference data which might be in one or another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

Imagine you have a database, which stores barters. For simplicity let's assume the barter system only allows you to exchange cats for dogs or dogs for cats (but IRL there might be more combinations).

To keep track of each barter act, one has `barters` table. A barter act consist of input and output (e.g. I trade one cat for 5 dogs - my input is one cat, output is 5 dogs). What is the best way to reference those from a `barter` row, given `cats` and `dogs` are different tables, and both can be input and output?

If these entities would be very similar, they could have been just `animals` instead of `cats` and `dogs` and the situation would have been pretty straightforward - a `barter` would have a foreign key, referencing id in `animals` table. But what if I really need different tables for those entities, what is the best practice?

E.g. I could store `input_type` and `output_type` which would contain the table name as a string, also I could have additional tables `inputs` and `outputs` where each row would have two columns - `table_name` and `id` (this way I could have real foreign key to reference an input or output). Which is better? What could be a better solution, not mentioned here?

Answer (score 0):

I would structure this with a intermediate table. 
In your example, i would add a table, let's say `Transaction`

Made of:

```
id //transaction id
input_barter_id
date //could be useful
```

Then i would create a link table, which stores all the trade objects, let's call it `Transaction_detail` , made of

```
id //could be not necessary
trasaction_id
output_barter_id
```

So in your example, if I trade 1 dog for 5 cats, i'll have 1 insert into `Transaction` table with the dog inside of it, and 5 insert into `Transaction_detail` table ,which references all the cats in that transaction .

Answer (score 0):

To pull data from the setup described you will need to build a query for each combination.

If the structure of the `cats` and `dogs` tables are the same, it might better to store the data in a single table and add a `type` column. If the structure is wildly different, separate tables might be better.

**For example**: if `cats` consists of `cat_name`, `DoB`, `Description` and `dogs` consists of `dog_name`, `DoB`, `Description` I would use just one table.

Remember that it's not just about storing the data, you need to be able to return it efficiently, whether in this application or via reports if needed. If you go down the route of separate tables, you reports will likely require procedures to generate dynamic SQL to retrieve the data.

Comment: indeed, the situation is trivial if you can store both in same table. My question is about what to do if you can't